# Is Jar Jar Binks a Sith Lord?

Tags: character, star-wars

I have found on the internet many sites (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATYSl.jpg), [here](http://www.techinsider.io/star-wars-fans-darth-jar-jar-theory-2015-11) and [here](https://digg.com/video/jar-jar-sith-lord-theory-explained-video) for example) that "prove" that Jar Jar Binks is a Sith Lord. My question is:

Is this only a fan theory, or is there an official explanation?

Comment: It's only a fan-theory. And a dumb one at that.

Comment: It's only dumb if you take it seriously. I think it's hilarious! "Meesa bein' Darth Big Ouch."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not in any way, shape, or form an official explanation of Jar Jar's. This was entirely a fan-devised "crazy theory", which just happens to have an interesting amount of *coincidental* supporting evidence. The theory originated [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/comments/3qvj6w) (where this kind of wild speculation is common and part of the regular entertainment amongst fans).

As far as this becoming "official" in canon, that's highly unlikely. In order for that to happen, Jar Jar would presumably have to appear in some subsequent canonical work. The theory even originally postulated that Jar Jar would

> play a central role in The Force Awakens

However, as far as anyone associated with the movies has said, that's not going to happen. For example, according to producer Kathleen Kennedy:

> “Jar Jar is definitely not in the movie,” she said to applause and cheers. [<sup>src</sup>](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/dec/07/star-wars-producer-confirms-jar-jar-binks-will-not-appear-in-the-force-awakens)

Comment: Well, that quote is nice, but it seems entirely unrelated to Jar Jar's previous actions at all. Doesn't seem relevant if he returns in future movies. As it stands, while being far less crazy, your answer seems to have as much weight as the theory itself.

Comment: The problem with this "fan theory" is that it supposes there was a secret "long term plan" for JJB as a Sith Lord; in order for that to be *officially* true, it would have to be revealed at some point in the future, but if we never see him again, that can't happen.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - While that's true, it could (theoretically) be revealed in another canon form such as a novel or the new comic series.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Ah, so add those elaborations into the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for not committing Eps 1-3 to memory, but I seem to recall that JJB was a bit clumsy.  Unless that theory postulates that his clumsiness was purposeful and all the trouble he caused due to his clumsiness was calculated to attempt to kill some of our heroes, I find it impossible to seriously consider the idea that a being that clumsy could be a Sith.

Comment: Thats the idea. Palatine pretends to be a frail old man.

Comment: The whole point of the theory is that Jar Jar has mastered the art of hiding in plain sight, seeming dumb and harmless (while still managing to infiltrate and spy on the Jedi, climb the ranks becoming a general and stand-in senator, and ultimately bring in the Empire). It compares his clumsy yet effective "dumb luck" based fighting to real-life "drunken master" style kung fu, and suggests that he *trained* Palpatine to also manipulate his rivals into underestimating him. It's a crazy theory, but also a surprising well executed one `:-)`

Comment: Oh, are THOSE the point? I thought it also had to do with him inspiring hatred by being so annoying, which leads people to the Dark Side.